# What are some bands similar to, the swing revival band, Big Bad Voodoo Daddy? Since this a revival band, whom are this band imitating?

Tags: jazz, swing

Here are some songs from this band:--

- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xphZkAiJve0)
- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19MMvOPd7Eg)
- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEWuZ0QBvlo)

---

Where can I find more information about:--

1. This band in particular
2. This type of music

---

**Direct Question**: Since this a revival band, whom are this band imitating?

---

**Prior Research**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bad_Voodoo_Daddy)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_revival)
- (https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0606926/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty close stylistically to the what the Benny Goodman Big Band were doing in the 1930s. [Sing, Sing, Sing](https://youtu.be/r2S1I_ien6A) is  one typical example of the style. If you like this, you might the bands of Artie Shaw, Duke Ellington, Count Basie or Cab Calloway. All of this music is available from any good music streaming service.
For an introduction to the swing music the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_music) page is probably a good start.